# displaying elements side by side

Tags: html, css

im trying to code a website and am a bit stumped. i've tried everything from
`display: inline-block;` to `float: left;` and `float: right;`
to no avail. I was wondering how I could get the `<i>` tags to be side by side rather than up and down?

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.top-navbar{
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.icons{
    width: 80px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.pic{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6.5px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.pic:hover{
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    background-color: red;
}
#top-nav-img{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="top-navbar">
            <div class="icons">
                <div class="pic">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" id="top-nav-img"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="pic">
                    <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" id="top-nav-img"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `.icons` to thin. Remember, that when you set `width` and `padding` to the element the values add up so if you have `40px` of width and `2px` or padding it will be `44px` (`2px` on each side) - unless you set `box-sizing: border-box` then `width` will be determined by value and paddings will be inside that values.

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.top-navbar{
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.icons{
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.pic{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6.5px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.pic:hover{
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    background-color: red;
}
#top-nav-img{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="top-navbar">
            <div class="icons">
                <div class="pic">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" id="top-nav-img"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="pic">
                    <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" id="top-nav-img"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.pic`s can not fit in `.icon` because the width of `.pic`s is greater than their parent so the second `.pic` goes to the second line. However, You can remove `width:80%;` from `.icon` or reduce the size of `.pic`s.

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.top-navbar{
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.icons{
    /* width: 80px; */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.pic{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6.5px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red; 
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.pic:hover{
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    background-color: red;
}
#top-nav-img{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="top-navbar">
            <div class="icons">
                <div class="pic">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" id="top-nav-img">1</i>
                </div>
                <div class="pic">
                    <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" id="top-nav-img">2</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline;` to the `.pic` css.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-navbar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.icons {
  width: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.pic {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6.5px 2px 2px 2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline;
}
.pic:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: red;
}
#top-nav-img {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-navbar">
    <div class="icons">
      <div class="pic">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" id="top-nav-img">a</i>
      </div>
      <div class="pic">
        <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x" id="top-nav-img">b</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```